# check validity of relational expression containing undefined variable in C

Tags: c

Is there a function in C which evaluates the validity of a relational expression without knowing the variable involved?

Examples:

```
int x;
(x < 10 && x > 1)
```

should return `true`, while an impossible expression like

```
int x;
(x > 10 && x < 1)
```

should return `false`.

Comment: The expression `(x > 10 && x < 1)` is always false. Why don't you use it in an if clause?

Comment: Maybe a static code analyzer can spot such statements.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

Using an uninitialized variable for anything other than writing to it is undefined behavior.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, which is that the boolean expression `(x > 10 && x < 1)` isn't making any sense.

Comment: No, I'm not. You know it doesn't make any sense, but you are human. The program will always attempt to use `x` to determine the outcome.

Comment: The question is a bit poorly formulated, but it is asking how to check the validity of a C expression. It is not asking "what will this code do".

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know, c has no build in "Expression validity function". You should code it your self.

Pseudo code:

```
bool Expr_valid(char* input)
{
    array[]=parse(input);   //parse input as you like into array
    evaluate(array);        //evaluate the parts of input according to your rules
    return evaluation result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is noting such functions which finds the validity of relational expression without variable defined.

Relational operators need to be employed to find relation between `two entities` which can be constants or variables defined only. Else it could be UB using undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function in C which evaluates the validity of a relational expression without knowing the variable involved

No.

What you should do is to compile with as many warnings enabled as possible. Good compilers give warnings like "condition is always true/false". And if the compiler still can't catch it, consider using an external static analysis tool, which will most likely find such bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/)

```
int x;

if (x > 10 && x < 0) {}
```

Output:

```
david@debian:~$ cppcheck --enable=all demo.c
Checking demo.c...
[demo.c:6]: (style) Variable 'x' is not assigned a value
[demo.c:8]: (warning) Logical conjunction always evaluates to false: x < 0 && x > 10.
[demo.c:8]: (error) Uninitialized variable: x
Checking usage of global functions..
```